# Form2 won't close and if I close it form1 will close as well. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

So I made this game in vb.net, and when you run it, it will ask you for a name, that's form2. The thing is, when you put a name, form2 will not close/disappear, and if you close it the whole game will close.

This is the code for form2:

```
Public Class Form2
Public Shared myMoney As Long

Public Shared welcome As String

Private Sub PositronButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PositronButton1.Click
    Form1.welcome = txtName.Text
    Form1.lblWelkom.Text = "Welcome," & " " & Form1.welcome
    MsgBox("Welcome," & " " & Form1.welcome & "." & "You recieved 500 money.")
    Form1.myMoney = 500
    Form1.lblMoney.Text = Form1.myMoney

    Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TopMost = True

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have wrong settings in your project.
Go to "Project", "Settings" and then have a look after "Shutdown mode".
Yours is probably set to "When last form closes". But you have to set "start form".

[image]

Also do not use `Form1.Show` because this is wrong, create an instance of it, then call it.

```
Dim frm As New Form1
frm.Show()
```

Also use `ShowDialog` for showing the Form2, it returns a DialogResult, and if it is "OK", you can close the form.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of setting Me.TopMost on the load event, you should call `Form2.Focus()` when you first open the Form in your Form1 code.

Secondly I am not sure how you are opening Form2, I assume you are using ShowDialog() In that case, in order to close Form2, you should call `Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`

Hope it Helps

Comment: Form2.Focus() is not a good solution. Also here there is no instance created to do this.
Better is: 

`Dim frm As New Form2` 
`frm.Show()` 
`frm.Focus()`